# TypeScript: how to return a field's type from a function

Tags: typescript

I want to design a function in TypeScript which access a field name of a complex structure and returns that field's type.
For example, there's a `Settings` type with several fields:

```
export interface Settings {
  apiConfig?: ApiConfig;
  presentation?: PresentationSettings;
}
```

I want to have a function `getSettings` which I could use as:

```
let cfg: ApiConfig = getSettings('apiConfig');
let ui: PresentationSettings = getSettings('presentation');
```

My first approach was usage of keyof:

```
function getSettings(name: keyof Settings): Settings[keyof Settings] {
  if (name == 'apiConfig') {
    return store.get(name) as ApiConfig;
  }
  if (name == 'presentation') {
    return store.get(name) as PresentationSettings;
  }
}
```

But it means that return type is basically a union of ApiConfig | PresentationSettings. So I'll have to cast:

```
const ui = <PresentationSettings>getSettings('presentation');
```

Non-ideal.

Next approach was generics:

```
export function getSettings<T extends Settings[keyof Settings]>(
  name: keyof Settings
```

it can be used as:

```
const ui = getSettings<PresentationSettings>('presentation');
```

But while implementing the function:

```
export function getSettings<T extends Settings[keyof Settings]>(
  name: keyof Settings 
{
  if (name == 'apiConfig') {
    return store.get(name) as ApiConfig;
  }
}
```

I'm getting error:
Type 'ApiConfig' is not assignable to type 'T'.
'ApiConfig' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'ApiConfig | PresentationSettings'.ts(2322)

So it has to be cast to `any`.
Non-ideal as well.

Is there any other ways?

Particularly I'd like to call it w/o any cast:
const ui = getSettings('presentation');
and have an instance of `PresentationSettings`.
Is that possible?

Comment: Note that `cfg` and `ui` need to have `undefined` as part of their type, since the properties are optional in `Settings`.

Comment: FWIW, here's how I'd approach it, but it's not different enough from Tobias' to justify posting an answer: https://tsplay.dev/m0n0aw

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function definitely needs to be generic. But `T` should not be the return type but rather just the key. The return type can use `T` to index `Settings`.

```
function getSettings<T extends keyof Settings>(name: T): Settings[T] {
  return {
    apiConfig: store.get(name) as ApiConfig,
    presentation: store.get(name) as PresentationSettings
  }[name]
}
```

If you want no errors in the implementation, you will have to use some kind of map structure like the one shown above.

The problem with this implementation is that each `store.get` call in the object will be eagerly executed which is not ideal if it is an expensive call. To avoid this you may just use a normal `switch` statement. But you are gonna need some assertions to silence the errors.

```
function getSettings<T extends keyof Settings>(name: T): Settings[T] {
  switch (name) {
    case "apiConfig": { return store.get(name) as Settings[T] }
    case "presentation": { return store.get(name) as Settings[T] }
    default: { return undefined as Settings[T] }
  }
}
```

If you want to be fully type-safe and have no eager execution of all paths you can use a map containing functions. The only downside here is the additional function call and that it might seem too verbose.

```
function getSettings<T extends keyof Settings>(name: T): Settings[T] {
  
  const mapping: {
    [K in keyof Settings]: () => Settings[K]
  } = {
    apiConfig: () => store.get(name) as ApiConfig,
    presentation: () => store.get(name) as PresentationSettings
  }

  return mapping[name]()
}
```

---

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictNullChecks=false#code/FAFwngDgpgBAghAlgYQPYDsBmiDmMC8MA3jAIYBcMAziAE6Lp4C+oksACrVFVOiKSEQYAylBCDGVAsRgAjSjXqMYLYFAAeEVLRAwGIKLUykAxrFHiGOKUWAwySNFlwB+SghQZsOANx2YEFw8fAJC6G4wnNy8-IIiYhLWfqqYAK7oJnHoMDhiFolUADwAKjAaBugAJlIA1lBgqJgw+VZUAHwAFOikALZQlMUAlJQtkgDaxQC6xP7+Jhg0MD2kEEiMlLb29mMA0nrZdQ1No9aTlB2DBG3NCa27k-5M0ptbK57OOOeX+Nc02lAAOlyIC6vSgl1IUg8Tm8ABp-PZAtEQlkvldqCB-kCxKC+hCpFFgrEwicqI9gP4uCBUrRsstVlYxt0+pMLsBVMAADZiGAmTCfeCOLy4aTA0kdADkbxhuAlgz83N0qUQlEJMVC8UsklFeVukklSKJGvQcp8QA)

Comment: *"If you want no errors in the implementation, you will have to use some kind of map structure like the one shown above."* Why, though? I did exactly what you have for the function signature but did the `if`/`else` route, and was **very** confused to get an error saying what I was returning wasn't assignable to `ApiConfig & PresentationSettings`. `&`?!?! I could swear I've done this sort of thing routinely, but the evidence suggests otherwise. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder - TypeScript almost never understand function implementations correctly. It will just look at each individual return statement to see if it *fully complies* with the return type. In this case, each return statement only partially complies, hence the error. Both return statements together would comply to the return type. But the compiler is not capable to reason about this as we do :)

Comment: Oh and also, there is no narrowing happening on `name` because it has a generic type.